# Power Apps - search through multiple subfolders of SharePoint Connection

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm building a Power App that I need to allow a user to enter a value, and the app will check a Sharepoint site if a field matches that value, then return another column's value.  I'm connected to the Sharepoint, but unfortunately all of the items I need to search through are in multiple (100s) of folders in the main Docs Folder (only 1 level down).

Another unfortunate thing is Power Automate won't work.  I have access to the SharePoint but Automate doesn't seem to have permission to perform a query.

The connection DOES provide a list of the subfolders if I use a combobox or dropdown, but I can't seem to drill down further to get the search results.